# How do I select a row with two columns joined by one column from another table?

Tags: sql, select

I'm sorry if my question doesn't make sense. I'm not sure how to word it. I just started self-studying SQL and there's something I want to do but I'm not sure how to do it. I'm hoping someone could help me out.

I have two tables where Table 1 is a list of students and Table 2 is a list of lab partners. Table 2 has students listed with their id numbers instead of names. The two tables can be joined together by student_id = student1_id (or student2_id).

Table 1

```
| student_id | student_name |
|------------|--------------|
| 01         | Alex         |
| 02         | Ben          |
| 03         | Chris        |
| 04         | Dave         |
```

Table 2

```
| group_number | student1_id | student2_id |
|--------------|-------------|-------------|
| 1            | 01          | 02          |
| 2            | 03          | 04          |
```

What would my select query look like if I wanted lab partners to show as names instead of id numbers? (See desired result below.)

Query result:

```
| group_number | (student_name of student1_id) | (student_name of student2_id) |
|--------------|-------------------------------|-------------------------------|
| 1            | Alex                          | Ben                           |
| 2            | Chris                         | Dave                          |
```

I'm actually stumped. I'm hoping someone could send me in the right direction. I would greatly appreciate the help!

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: something like SELECT group_number, a.name, b.name from table_2 as t inner join table_1 as a on t.student1_id = a.studend id inner join table_2 as b on t.student2_id = b.student_id

Answer (score 1):

You would join on the id columns with the Table1(that holds the name of students) twice-> one for student_1's name and one for student_2's name

```
select t2.group_number
       ,t11.student_name as student_name_1
       ,t12.student_name as student_name_2
  from Table2 t2
  join Table1 t11
    on t2.student1_id=t11.student_id
  join Table1 t12
    on t2.student2_id=t12.student_id
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Follow up question, what do you call t2, t11, and t12? When you did it, what's it called? I'd like to read more about it in the documentation. Are they the same as "as"?

Comment: @ChrisSimmons . . . Those are called *table aliases*.